# JAVA - Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) VS Calender.YEAR

Tags: java, calendar

What is the difference between these 2 lines of code? Or are they the same?

```
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

and this:

```
int year = Calender.YEAR;
```

Comment: what happened when you printed them out?

Comment: `Calender.YEAR` is a *constant* with the value of `1`.

Comment: On the Calendar.getInstance() I get '2016', which is good. And on the second one I get '1'. But what does the Calendar.YEAR do excactly?

Answer (score 0):

The first part is getting today's year.

The second just provides the integer used to identify "Year" as a concept in the Calendar. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.YEAR It's a different way of doing enumerations, with `static final` integers.

Comment: Did that answer your question?